# $\int_{-a}^{a}f_{1}(x) dx=\int_{-a}^{a}f_{2}(x)dx$ implies $f_{1}(x)=f_{2}(x)$?

Tags: integration

This might be look a stupid question but if i have two functions: $f_{1}(x)$ and $f_{2}(x)$ and I know that $\int_{-a}^{a}f_{1}(x)dx=\int_{-a}^{a}f_{2}(x)dx$ do this imply that $f_{1}(x)=f_{2}(x)$?

Comment: No. $f_1 = sin (\pi x/a)$, $f_2 = 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily.  For example, consider two odd functions.

Comment: True! but what if there's an additional constrain for the integral to be different from zero?

Comment: Consider two odd functions plus some other function with nonzero integral.

Comment: It's easy to find a counterexample.